# SQL statement to get the titles of the books that were not ordered

Tags: sql

I am try to do list all book titles and the first and last names of the customer(s) who ordered each title.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customer#, lastname || ', ' || firstname "Customer", title
  FROM customers c, orders o, orderitems i, books b
  WHERE c.customer# = o.customer#
  AND o.order# = i.order# AND i.isbn = b.isbn;
```

I still not got an idea how can I get the titles of the books that were not ordered.
Thank you.

Structure:

- Customer: Customer#, lastname, firstname
- Order: Customer#, orderdate
- Orderitems: Order#, item#, isbn
- Books: Title, isbn

Comment: You need a `left join` or `not exists`, depending on exactly what you want (unclear). Please use proper join syntax, not that deprecated `,` cross-join

Comment: can you share more information about the database that you are using e.g. Microsoft Sql Server, Orcale etc , the type of sql that you guys are using suchh as T-SQL, PL-SQL, Hive Query Language (HQL)

Comment: I have added more info to my database. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports anti-joins then do an anti-join between orders and books table using the isbn as join key, this will give you the records for book that have not been ordered yet.

```
select b.title as title
from books b
leftanti join orderitems oi
on b.isbn = oi.isbn
```

Otherwise you can do a left outer join with books as left table and orders as right table and then filter for records in the output that had no match in the orders table. This will give you the output you want.

```
select title from
(select b.title as title , b.isbn as isbn , oi.orderno as orderno
from books b
left outer join orderitems oi
on b.isbn = oi.isbn) temp
where orderno IS NULL
```

As suggested by @Charlieface, you can also try

```
select b.title from books b
where b.isbn not exists in 
(select distinct(isbn) from orderitems) temp;
```

PS: I primarily use Give Query language (HQL) so my the syntax is based on the same. Depending on your database and your type of SQL you will have to adjust the queries accordingly.

Comment: I have added the structure of my database. Thank you.

Comment: I have modified my answer based on your update :)

Comment: So, just one more question: How can I get also the last name and first name include all the title, isbn and ordernumber?

Comment: @congdanh1594 I am a bit confused, do you want to include the firstname lastname and other details for books/titles that have been ordered? Because your initial question was about getting titles for books which have never been ordered.  Perhaps if you can reword your question better and post some example of the output you are expecting, it would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
  SELECT o.order,c.customer,c.lastname,c.firstname,b.title
  FROM orders o
  JOIN orderitems oi 
  ON oi.order = o.order
  JOIN books b
  ON b.isbn = oi.isbn;
```

It would be nice to include `Order ID` in your results, to my opinion.